# PyQt. Show OS process as I go?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

Right now I am using Python to loop copy lots of files. While copying, I tell PyQt to append feedback to a QTextEdit:

```
for src in sources:
    shutil.copy(src, dst)
    self.feedback.append("Copying " + src)
```

(`self.feedback` is the QTextEdit).

When I start my script, PyQt freezes until all the copies are completed, before displaying everything all at once.

How can I make it so that each feedback is shown in real time as the files are being copied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your task is completely IO-bound, you can simply tell Qt to process any pending gui events before starting the next copy operation:

```
for src in sources:
    self.feedback.append('Copying: %s' % src)
    QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
    shutil.copy(src, dst)
```